SRS (Sender Rewriting Scheme): Email forwarding does not work
I have an Email-Adress which is a pure forwarding, on a Mailserver A and lands in a Mailbox on Mailserber B. Now I have this situation: the Mailserver A implements the SRS Scheme, meaning the sender envelope gets a modification, see wikipedia:
ORIGINAL
envelope sender:     alice@example.org
envelope recipient:  bob@example.com
REWRITTEN
envelope sender:     SRS0=HHH=TT=example.org=alice@example.com
envelope recipient:  bob@example.net
The problem is, Mailserver B does not implement SRS and flags the mails as "Spoof", the mails do not get into the mailbox on Server B, which is very bad. Mailserver A says they cannot configure the server not to do SRS, Mailserver B says they will implement sometimes SRS, until then they cannot do anything. Is there any solution to this problem? I was thinking, if I forward the mail to an intermediate Mailserver which can delete the envelope modification? Is something like this possible?
Thank you
I didn't try anything yet
